# Как работает сложная адаптивная верстка?

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend

Не работал с фреймворками, однако клиент хочет что-бы я использовал бутстрап, стоит ли учится бутстрапу, действительно ли он ускоряет верстку, или проще использовать свои готовые наработки?

И еще вопрос, какие инструменты нужно использовать чтобы была такая верстка на лету?

ПК:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мобильный:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

бутстрап может ускорить верстку, если вы уже в нем достаточно натренировались. Там реализовано куча классов за Вас. Особенно удобно делать адаптивы. Нужно или нет, тут решать Вам. Я к примеру его использую только если нужно что-то быстро слепить. Тк подключать лишние кб к сайту я не люблю, и в серьезном проекте не стал бы его использовать, а написал бы свои классы.

Вертка на лету - попробуйте browsersync, что ли))

Answer (score 1):

Советую брать из Бутстрапа только сетку, (иначе будет слишком тяжеловесный проект, это может быть полезно если верстаете крупный проект с повторяющимися элементами дизайна) Если знакомы с верстой то изучения сетки займет не больше пару часов. В остальном это удобный инструмент доведенный до ума.